# Error with scalar variable

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to insert in the table at the database using the following code:

```
If MsgBox("Do you want to save '" & Me.TxtItemID.Text & "' & '" & Me.TxtRetail.Text & "'", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "(NS) - Save?") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then


 Me.asInsert.SaveValueIN("INSERT INTO LUP_ITEMSZM (nCODE, sITEM_DESC, nUNIT_COST, nSTOCK, nUNIT_PRICE, sPIECE_DESC, sPIECE_PACK, sSTATUS , sSupplier_NAME) VALUES(@nCode, @sITEM_DESC,  , @nUNIT_COST,@nSTOCK, @nUNIT_PRICE,  @sPIECE_DESC,@sPIECE_PACK, @sSTATUS,  @sSupplier_NAME)")

 SqlInsertCommand1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@nCODE", SqlDbType.BigInt)).Value = Me.TxtItemID.Text.Trim
 SqlInsertCommand1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@sITEM_DESC", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = Me.txtItemDesc.Text.Trim
 SqlInsertCommand1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@nUNIT_COST", SqlDbType.Money)).Value = Me.TxtCost.Text.Trim
 SqlInsertCommand1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@nSTOCK", SqlDbType.BigInt)).Value = Me.TxtQtyStock.Text.Trim
 SqlInsertCommand1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@nUNIT_PRICE", SqlDbType.Money)).Value = Me.TxtRetail.Text.Trim
 SqlInsertCommand1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@sPIECE_DESC", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = Me.TxtPcsDesc.Text.Trim
 SqlInsertCommand1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@sPIECE_PACK", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = Me.TxtPPP.Text.Trim
 SqlInsertCommand1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@sSTATUS", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = Me.DmnStatus.SelectedIndex
 SqlInsertCommand1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@sSupplier_NAME", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = Me.CmbSupplier.SelectedItem.col1

  Me.TxtItemID.Focus()
End If
```

I'm keep getting the the following error:

must declare the scalar variable @ncode

Kindly need your assitance

Thank you

Comment: Probably you need to add your parameters BEFORE executing the query, but this question is totally unclear. How SqlInsertCommand1 relates to your query? What is the code of SaveValueIN?

Comment: You've also two commas after `@sITEM_DESC`

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. @ncode is case sensitive. Try giving @nCODE instead of @ncode in your insert query where you are using the scalar.

```
Me.asInsert.SaveValueIN("INSERT INTO LUP_ITEMSZM (nCODE, sITEM_DESC, nUNIT_COST, nSTOCK, nUNIT_PRICE, sPIECE_DESC, sPIECE_PACK, sSTATUS , sSupplier_NAME) VALUES(@nCODE, @sITEM_DESC,  , @nUNIT_COST,@nSTOCK, @nUNIT_PRICE,  @sPIECE_DESC,@sPIECE_PACK, @sSTATUS,  @sSupplier_NAME)")
```

While adding parameter you are adding as @nCODE , and in insert query you are using it as @ncode. Both should be the same.

```
SqlInsertCommand1.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@nCODE", SqlDbType.BigInt)).Value = Me.TxtItemID.Text.Trim
```